# VueJS: How to set props to slot elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to set *props* on **slot** element?

**Component**

```
<script id="templ-container" type="text/x-template">
    <div>
        <p>top</p>
        <slot class="borders"></slot>
        <p>bottom</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**App**

```
<container>
    <p>Aliquam et enim congue, luctus nulla vel...</p>
</container>
```

**Expected End Result**

```
<p>top</p>
<p class="borders">Aliquam et enim congue, luctus nulla vel...</p>
<p>bottom</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg48gtgd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the slot is replaced, you should do something like:

```
<p>top</p>
<div class="borders"><slot></slot></div>
<p>bottom</p>
```

Or create it as another component